# External API not working after attaching VPC to LAmbda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am calling one external endpoint from my lambda, I am able to access the URL when no VPC is attached to my Lambda but as soon as I attach the vpc, the external api call stopped working.

1. https://google.com works even after attaching the lambda which means that internet access is not blocked.
2. Security group with outbound rule is attached to the lambda and two private subnets.
3. The external api is a api gateway invoke url (it does not have a custom domain). This url is of a different AWS account. This url is working on postman, and it works through lambda also when I detach the vPC
4. NAT gatway is configured, it is accessing all external URLS except this one URL because this is a api gateway invoke URL of a differnt account. https://*******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443/abc.
5. I am getting 403 forbidden after attaching VPC

As per my analysis, this could be the problem statement but I am not able to figure out the issue: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure a NAT gateway.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: I have already configured NAT gateway that is why it is able to access https://google.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it a private api gateway or public, have you tried removing :443 and just using the api gateway url